# select content array of arrays concatenated php

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

**I have this XML:**

```
<Interface>
<Product>
 <ProductFeature Localized="0" ID="21355773" Local_ID="0" Value="TFT"      CategoryFeature_ID="92510" CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883" No="100030"      Presentation_Value="TFT" Translated="0" Mandatory="0" Searchable="0">
 <LocalValue Value="TFT">
 <Measure ID="29">
 <Signs/>
 </Measure>
 </LocalValue>
 <Feature ID="9104">
 <Measure ID="29" Sign="">
 <Signs/>
 </Measure>
 <Name ID="761217" langid="5" Value="Tipo di display"/>
 </Feature>
 </ProductFeature>
 <ProductFeature Localized="0" ID="21355772" Local_ID="0" Value="0.065536" CategoryFeature_ID="51558" CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883" No="100024" Presentation_Value="0,065536M" Translated="0" Mandatory="0" Searchable="0">
 <LocalValue Value="0.065536">
 <Measure ID="30">
 <Signs>
 <Sign ID="6740" langid="5">
 <![CDATA[ M ]]>
 </Sign>
 </Signs>
 </Measure>
 </LocalValue>
 <Feature ID="942">
 <Measure ID="30" Sign="M">
 <Signs>
 <Sign ID="6740" langid="5">
 <![CDATA[ M ]]>
 </Sign>
 </Signs>
 </Measure>
 <Name ID="460091" langid="5" Value="Colori del display"/>
 </Feature>
 </ProductFeature>
 </Product>
 </Interface>
```

to extract the single content instance ID = 21355773
I tried it with functions:

```
$xml->xpath('//ProductFeature[@CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883"]');
```

but the result is always the same array, I can not pull out the piece of content.

How can I extract the contents single?

---

#### Solved

After some testing I came to the solution

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$xml->xpath('//ProductFeature[@CategoryFeature_ID="92510" and @CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883"]/@Presentation_Value')
```

Comment: That array is unreadable, please reformat it so that we can get a better sense of the structure

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change this line:

```
$xml->xpath('//ProductFeature[@CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883"]');
```

To this line:

```
$items = $xml->xpath('//ProductFeature[@CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883" and @ID="21355773"]');
```

Now the `$items` will be an array of [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) objects which contains 1  object  that you can get with `$items[0]`

Then for example you can get the attribute values like this:

```
$items = $xml->xpath('//ProductFeature[@CategoryFeatureGroup_ID="6883" and @ID="21355773"]');
$id = (string)$items[0]->attributes()->ID;
$langId = (string)$items[0]->Feature->Name->attributes()->langid;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/IXc5K)

Comment: Thank you works perfectly, you have been very kind.
Thanks again @The fourth bird

Comment: @user3582980 You are welcome. If this answer helped you solving your problem you can always consider marking the answer as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: I have only one problem, when the field is empty blocks me the script ex. I have multiple image $Img1 = (string)$feature[0]->ProductGallery->ProductPicture[0]->attributes()->Pic;
$Img2 = (string)$feature[0]->ProductGallery->ProductPicture[1]->attributes()->Pic;
If ProductPicture[1] don't exist , the script is blocked